# Jekyll - Front Matter Defaults Not Recognized

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to get used to Jekyll, and the problem I have isn't helping. It doesn't seem to recognize that I have any. This is for both `layout` and for `title`.

**Defaults:**

```
default:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      layout: "post"
      title: "Default Title"
```

I have looked throughout the web (and Stack Overflow), and found solutions that didn't work for me:

- I have a Front Matter in index.html.
- I quit Jekyll serving and started it up multiple times.

**EDIT:** The repository is [hosted here.](https://github.com/MathManiac0/MathManiac0.github.io)

Comment: Typo : default: -> defaults:

Comment: Thanks - if you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your variable : `default` -> `defaults`